# Bitmap в Emgu.Cv.Image c#

Tags: c#, изображения, bitmap, emgucv

Использую библеотеку Emgu.CV. Мне надо надо передать в качестве аргумента в конструктор класса Image - Bitmap. Но у меня выдает ошибку.

[image: Ошибка]

Вот реализация объекта Bitmap.

[image: Инициализация]

Вот кусок кода, где я реализую установку изображения в Tesseract.

```
    tesseract.SetImage(new Image<Bgr, byte>(bitmap1);
    tesseract.Recognize();
```

Comment: со скобкой в конце тоже ошибка tesseract.SetImage(new Image<Bgr, byte>(bitmap1));  ?

Comment: @АрхиповВладимир да. там проблема не в скобках.

Comment: пишет, что передаёте bitmap, а ждёт byte[,,,], скорее всего про new Image, в документации ```public void SetImage(
 Bitmap bitmap
)``` попробуйте ```tesseract.SetImage(bitmap1);```

Comment: @АрхиповВладимир ошибка "не удалось преобразовать из system.drawing.bitmap в Emgu.CV.IInputArray"

Comment: значит tesseract.SetImage(new Image<Bgr, byte>(bitmap1)); верно, но не так создаёте картинку, по коду не совсем понятно, Вы создаёте пустую картинку, а потом пытаетесь её распознать

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Emgu.CV 4.3

Начиная с версии 4.3 `Bitmap` преобразуется в `Image<Bgr, byte>` следующим образом:

```
var bmp = new Bitmap(width, height, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);
Image<Bgr, Byte> img1 = bmp.ToImage<Bgr, byte>();
```

Ответ взят из [англоязычного SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62464845/6468198)

---

### Emgu.CV 4.4

В версии 4.4 для того, чтобы появился метод `ToImage<Bgr, byte>();` помимо `Emgu.CV` нужно отдельно установить следующие пакеты:

- Emgu.CV.Bitmap
- Emgu.CV.runtime.windows

Comment: Не работает. Пишет что Bitmap не содержит определения ToImage.

Comment: Удалил версию 4.4 и поставил 4.3. И заработало...

Comment: @Григорий Видимо, в 4.4 опять решили поменять метод создания `Image<Bgr, Byte>` из `Bitmap`

Comment: @Григорий обновил ответ для версии 4.4